# POSTing key/value pairs to web api

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have a method in my web api controller that looks something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string DoRun(Guid id, IDictionary<string,object> parameters)
    {
        string val = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return val;
    }
```

And the problem I am having is that I can't get the `parameters` to actually bind. It does attempt to read it from the body of the request because `val` is an empty string, but the `Count` of `parameters` is zero (removing the `parameters` argument entirely, you can see the data in `val` and it'll echo it back as a json string).

Here's how I'm posting (which might also be the problem):

```
    var dummyPayload = {
        regions: [111, 222, 333],
        code: 55661,
        private: true,
        level: "foo"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "../../api/MyController/DoRun?id=7EEB1650-1CB7-41DB-8C0B-1016ACA0E568",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(dummyPayload),
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    });
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Yeah, I tried that, it didn't make a difference. Clearly it's trying to read from the body anyway.

Comment: yeah, forget that. Your `parameters` parameter is expecting JSON data with "key" and "value" members. If the shape is fixed, can you just define an object that matches your data (for the receiving parameter)?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: I tried processing my object into an array of key/value pairs, but that didn't seem to help. My data in that case looked like `[{"key":"regions","value":[111,222,333]},{"key":"code","value":55661},{"key":"private","value":true},{"key":"level","value":"foo"}]`

Comment: This is a semi-serious suggestion, but I wonder what happens if you make the parameter a `dynamic` object? Is the mapping smart enough to just fill it? Try `dynamic parameters` :)

Comment: Ah... I think I see the problem with your earlier Key/Value attempt... it can't convert things like "[111,222,333]" to an object. Not enough information. Again `dynamic` may have solved that one (as in `IDictionary<string,dynamic>`).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: No, dynamic doesn't work unfortunately. The dynamic object has no properties (`parameters.GetType().GetProperties()` returns and empty array of `PropertyInfo`). The url isn't a problem, it's relative to where happen to be calling it from and will be fixed eventually. Either way, it does hit the controller because I have a break point there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45486/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-matt-burland)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the media type of your request body using `contentType`. `dataType` sets the `Accept` header and `contentType` sets `Content-Type`.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../../api/MyController/DoRun?id=7EEB1650-1CB7-41DB-8C0B-1016ACA0E568",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(dummyPayload),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
    }).done(function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    });
```